# Sequelize best practices syncing database development vs. production

Tags: javascript, sql, orm, sequelize.js, migration

The [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#synchronization-in-production) for Sequelize states that `sequelize.sync()` shoudln't be used on production, as it is potentially destructive. Instead, migrations should be used.

Therefore, I am wondering what the best practices are for using `sequelize.sync()`.

Is it common to use environment variables to check if the current environment is development? Like such:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sequelize.sync({ force: true });
}
```

That way, the database would only be synced in a development environment.

Otherwise, is it common this time to simply not use sync at all, even in a development environment, and use regular migrations?

Comment: There is none a migration gives you control over the changes, that will be made, sync doesn't , so you should not use it

Comment: And decision to use either `sync` or `migrations` depending on environment is also a bad idea. There should be only one approach to keep DB structure up-to-date: migrations.